# Is there a way to create a block template that is not limited to a post type?

Tags: templates, block-editor

So, I have been reading up on block templates and from what I understand, they limit the ability to create them to one per post type. I just need to be able to add groupings of blocks without having to be limited to a single instance of that template per post type. Can you create a block that is a group other blocks so that you can change out the block if needed?

Eg. One of the pages that I have has a dashed divider between a list of stylized file links and video embeds on the left and text details on the right. On another page, the video embed is on left, links on right and the content below, with no dash between the top two. This is all determined by custom fields that were saved in the post meta. Since Gutenberg changed all of that I am working on finding a good solution for migrating to WordPress 5.0.

Any information is appreciated!

Comment: the question is a bit unclear for me: "Can you create a block that is a group other blocks so that you can change out the block if needed?" do you mean block groups created and saved in the editor?

Comment: Basically, I want to make what the templates does now, but limited to a set of blocks like layout plus a couple others. And, since you can't declare more than one per post type it limits me to what you can do. I don't understand how it all works yet because the wordpress documentation sucks and I am having a hard time finding what I need to figure out whether what I am trying to do is viable.

Comment: The template of a block with Innerblocks component is a property of that block and its different from the property to make the block only appear once. I mean that you can have a block with a certain template appear only once or several times. For example, the columns block has a template applied but can be added several times. And the page template which can be set in the CPT registration is related to the Innerblocks template, but it fixes the layout of the page.

Comment: What I think you are looking for is a block which can change its template based on a setting. The ideal is that this setting is an attribute of the block (its easier to implement). But it can also be a meta attribute, or something external to the block. Also this block should be the only block in the root level, and this root level should be fixed to not having more blocks. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I am looking to create several blocks that contain starting blocks for each type that I need. I am reading through the source code and I am starting to understand it a bit more. Sadly, they much work to do on the documentation. It's nowhere near as comprehensive as the PHP documentation.

Comment: Im not sure what does "starting blocks" looks like, if you have some sketches it might be easier to understand. As I said Im not sure I fully understand the idea, but it might be easier having different block types rather than having one which changes depending on settings.

Comment: Starting blocks as in a set of blocks that can be edited and or added to.